# Ionic 3 - Lost form data when when I use pop function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a questionnaire App with more than three pages .. I use NavCtrl to go to next page >> but when I go back using back to the previous page using NavCtrl the page displays all forms blank and the data is lost.

Please Help Me :(

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement that. Full documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Using `navCtrl.push(page)` to navigate is one option. In that case you have a root page, that is set up in your `app.component.ts`.

When you return from pushed page by using the back button or closing the view, the root page should be the same.

**Note**: You need to differentiate between `root` pages and `push` pages. The `root` page is your active page, when you then push pages, the root pages does not change. But when you change the `root` page, by using `setRoot`, Lifecycle Events, constructor, ... are called.